# How many sets with such conditions?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

We have S sets.
$$M = \{M_1, M_2, ..., M_S\}$$

Overall there are n elements, and $$|M_i| = 6,  \forall i$$

$$|M_i\cap M_j| \neq 2,  \forall i,j$$

So, the question is: what is the maximum number of sets(S), that satisfy this conditions?

I don't have any idea how to solve it. Teacher says that first of all I should find upper and lower bounds on S.

I'm not good at this field, so could you, please, give some ideas or adivces?

Comment: Are these conditions exactly what you mean?  It seems that there can be countably many sets (actually, there could be an uncountable amount if we like).  For instance if $n = 6$, can't we just take $M_1 = \{ 1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and $M_1 = M_2 = \ldots$ yielding countably many sets?

Comment: @MarcusM Assuming standard notation, $M$ is a set, not a multiset, so you can assume the $M_i$'s are distinct.

Comment: @Tad,  Ah, I see what you mean.  Not to get super pedantic, but then we're technically trying to find the maximum cardinality of $M$, as we can always write $M = \{M_1,M_1,M_1,...\}$ and still only have $|M| = 1$.  However, your interpretation is certainly what is intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Partial answer) Here's a lower bound which I suspect is sharp.  Fix $3$ elements, and complete them to $6$-subsets in all possible ways.  This gives $\binom{n-3}{3}$ $6$-subsets, all of whose pairwise intersections have size at least $3$.

Comment: And we will have $n \cdot (n-1) \cdot (n-3) \cdot \binom{n-3}{3}$? 
It's correct, as I think, but without upper bound it's difficult to say what the S.

Comment: I'm claiming the maximal $S$ is at least $\binom{n-3}{3}$.